# Linux find -type f ignored

Tags: linux, zsh

I'm creating a cron job, that will find all `*.log*` files (it will be used to remove them later, when it works).

The find command looks like this:

```
find /data/dg  \( -path /data/dg/kf/data -o -path /data/dg/pg/data \) -prune -o -name "*.log*" -type f
```

And it should find all files with name "*.log*" that are not in directories `/data/dg/kf/data` and `/data/dg/pg/data`

However the output this command gives contains also the directories.

```
...
/data/dg/kf/log/controller.log.2019-09-08-22
/data/dg/kf/log/server.log.2019-09-09-07
/data/dg/kf/data
/data/dg/pg/log/postgresql-2019-09-27_000000.log
/data/dg/pg/log/postgresql-2019-09-27_100859.log
/data/dg/pg/log/postgresql-2019-09-27_102411.log
/data/dg/pg/data
/data/dg/sim/log/sim_2019-09-27-11.0.log
/data/dg/sim/log/sim_2019-09-27-12.0.log
...
```

It seems that `-type f` doesn't work. What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put `-type f` right after `/data/dg`

```
find /data/dg -type f  -not -path "/data/dg/kf/data*" -not -path "/data/dg/pg/data*" -name "*.log*"
```

Comment: Try now. I've fix it. Escape characters during copy

Comment: Thank you, but now it doesn't ignore the directories,`/data/dg/kf/data` and `/data/dg/pg/data`

Comment: Try now. Fix with -not -path

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.